# how to change color of auto text typing in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

hallo everybody can u help me to change color.
how to use special color text. we take a few examples such as:

> "discuss about **HTML**"

in html text you want to change to a different color without the **`<color code>`** tags like

> "discussing about `HTML`"
> from the HTML can be set with color.
> sorry im first here.

can we you use with css?
thank you!
[this my example capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQKfJ.jpg)

Comment: hi @INL Welcome to SO, what do u mean by "in html text you want to change to a different color without the"?

Comment: Please try to edit your question so that we can understand what you are asking. It's unclear.

Comment: thats my picture was update on the post, any solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `color` CSS property. Using the `style` attribute it would like this:

```html
<span style="color: green;">Colored text</span>
```

Or, using a class:

```css
.green-text {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<span class="green-text">Colored text</span>
```